# small cakes/muffins not rising correctly

Tags: cake, rising

My small cakes for example muffins are not rising correctly.  They rise lopsidedly and spill over the paper cases.  Nothing wrong with oven.  I've tried various things, eg wetter mixture, drier mixture, smaller quantity in case, larger quantity in case, it's as if the fan  is blowing the cake mixture off to once side.  Doesn't happen with all my cakes mainly the small ones.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide more details and information that might help us answer?   What have you checked for the oven?  What kinds of recipe?   Do you have a photo?  Does this happen when convection is turned off?

Comment: You said that your oven is OK, but if there is any doubt, also refer to this answer: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/29488/4638. (The other answers are specific to macarons and don't necessarily apply to muffins)

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet you're using egg foam for leavening which is notoriously finicky. Despite protestations that it can't be overmixed, it also can't be undermixed! So make sure it's well incorporated into the batter before loading up. Batter color should be even.

For other considerations, similar rules apply if you're using chemical leavening: your tins/cups/pans need to be spotlessly clean. This is my method: Insides are then lubed up to the top with butter or shortening. The insides should then be tossed with a thin coating of something, either sugar or chocolate powder (basically some dry substance). Load your batter in to 2/3 the height of the pan (tends to be roughly the same regardless of the size of the pan for me). Do so very neatly so as not to spill batter and muck up the pan. Also give it a slight few taps to work unsuspended air bubbles up to the surface.